# Is it possible to add or modify element at the head of linked blocking queue?

Tags: java, queue, synchronized

Or maybe will be better to use other class for synchronized access to data?

Comment: If you have only one consumer, you can use peak().  However if you have multiple consumers, you need to rethink you approach as you could a range of problems. In this case it is best to remove() the entry before changing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `LinkedBlockingDeque` if you want to manipulate both ends of a queue.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the element at the head of a linked blocking queue (use `peek()` to obtain it. If you want to add elements to the head of a data structure then use a [LinkedBlockingDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but [LinkedBlockingDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) provides both FIFO and LIFO operations (similar to a Stack). Maybe it does what you want.